# Where should I store 30+ UIColors for quick reference?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicolor

I want to have 30+ constant UIColors so I can easily access them in my app.  I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
 [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor skyColor]];
 [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor dirtColor]];
 [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yankeesColor]];
```

How can I do this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Define a category for `UIColor`:

In UIColor+MyColors.h:

```
@interface UIColor (MyColors)

+ (UIColor *)skyColor;
+ (UIColor *)dirtColor;
// and the rest of them

@end
```

In UIColor+MyColors.m:

```
@implementation UIColor (MyColors)

+ (UIColor *)skyColor {
    static UIColor color = nil;
    if (!color) {
        // replace r, g, and b with the proper values
        color = [UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:1];
    }

    return color;
}

+ (UIColor *)dirtColor {
    static UIColor color = nil;
    if (!color) {
        // replace r, g, and b with the proper values
        color = [UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:1];
    }

    return color;
}

// and the rest

@end
```

Edit:

As Martin R points out, a more modern approach to initializing the static `color` variable would be:

```
+ (UIColor *)skyColor {
    static UIColor color = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t predicate = 0;

    dispatch_once(&predicate, ^{
        // replace r, g, and b with the proper values
        color = [UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:1];
    });

    return color;
}
```

This may actually be overkill in this case since there is no bad side-effect if two threads happen to initialize the `nil` static variable at the same time using the original code. But it is a better habit to use `dispatch_once`.

Comment: Why do you use a static color variable instead of returning the result of colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha?  Speed for subsequent requests?  Won't the color var get overridden every time a new color is requested?

Comment: @JeffCompton I used a static so the color only gets created once. It's minor optimization. Each static is scoped to the method it is in so they do not interfere which each other. No different than having a non-static variable with the same name in two different methods.

Comment: Remark: Using `dispatch_once()` might be the more "modern" way and would make the initialisation thread-safe.

Comment: @MartinR You are correct. I was actually too lazy to type that much when I originally answered the question and using the "old approach" has no bad side-effects. But I updated the answer to show the use of `dispatch_once`. Thanks.

Comment: @downvoter - care to explain why you down voted this answer? Spread your wisdom so we can all learn from it.

Comment: Upvoted, but FWIW I'd point out that best practices suggest using a prefix for category methods on system classes.  (e.g., `RM_skyColor`, `RM_dirtColor` ...)

Comment: @ArtGillespie That's a good practice if there is any chance at all of a possible name collision.

Comment: If you have lots of colours, I think a `return MAKE_STATIC([UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:1])` macro would go nicely here. Macros aren't always evil.

Answer (score 1):

You can add lines like this:

```
#define kFirstColor [UIColor whiteColor]
#define kSecondColor [UIColor colorWithRed:100.0/255 green:100.0/255 blue:100.0/255 alpha:1.0]
```

At the beginning of a class or add a Color.h header to your project and import it when needed.

```
#import "Color.h"
```

Then you can use your custom colors this way:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = kSecondColor;
```

Comment: Using defines this way makes for harder-to-understand code in the sense that the preprocessor directive masks the true type/nature of kFirstColor and so on. @rmaddy's approach is more verbose, but is a better solution in terms of code clarity and performance.

Comment: @Beppe It's an approach, it's just not a very good one. The negative vote was probably indicating that. Negative votes don't necessarily mean an answer was wrong, only that it was not as good as another answer. Personally I feel that voting up the right answer would be a better practice, but each SO user has their own approach to points.

Comment: #defines aren't really a bad approach. The code is short (one line per color), thread-safe, type-safe, easily understandable and modifiable. There are places where #defines can get programmers into trouble, but this doesn't seem like one of them.