# How do I create a method for a specific colour to put into my code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, uicolor

I am a beginner and am currently trying to make a method for a specific custom colour. I will be using it to change the background colours of certain buttons.

I am trying to make it so that I can simply type `myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor customColor];` instead of having to type `myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.643 green:0.643 blue:0.643 alpha:1];`.

Comment: See also [Where should I store 30+ UIColors for quick reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18038953/where-should-i-store-30-uicolors-for-quick-reference).

Comment: As a side node, you should always prefix method names with a custom prefix - like `palette_customRed` - when adding methods to system classes, something the accepted answers of the duplicate questions are not doing.

Answer (score 0):

You need  write category class for UIColor something like

in UIColor+Custom.h:

define color enums something like

```
 typedef enum color {RED=0,GREEN, PURPLE, YELLOW} color; //define more enums for other custom color


@interface UIColor (Custom)

+ (UIColor *)customColor:(color)color;


@end



@implementation UIColor (Custom)

+ (UIColor *)customColor:(color)color 
{
    static UIColor color = nil;
    switch (color) {
    case RED:
        color = [UIColor reColor];
        break;
    case YELLOW:
        color = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.643 green:0.643 blue:0.643 alpha:1]; //just a example not right rgb for yellow
        break;
    //Similarly write for other color's     
    default:
        break;


return color;
```

}